# Surge protectors: Do they make anything like "Power Center" anymore?

Tags: surge-protection, powerstrip

See this:

[image]

It's called Power Center and I am STILL using the same one that I got with my first PC back in 1995!  It still works, but I think it's time to upgrade to a new one, but I cannot find these anywhere.  I search for surge protector, but all I see are the ones you set on the floor with plugs only (no switches that control the power to each plug).  I love the one I have because I can set my monitor on top of it so it's right in front of me at all times.

Is there a specific name for this particular type of "power strip" so I can search more effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust me they do still exist. It's just that they aren't as common because everyone goes as cheap and small as possible.

Here you go, I'm not recommending this one, just proving to you they're still made.

[Tripp Lite TMC-6 6-Outlet Under Monitor Surge Protector](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AKA90)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one in my search, but only that one.  I don't know why these are so rare when they're so handy and convenient.

Comment: I think manufacturers are moving away from it because of the popularity of the UPS market for businesses. Personally I like the idea of UPS/Surge protectors as well. Given most of them are heavy and pretty much make use of unused space anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that many of the new "smart" surge supressors will shut down devices automatically once a primary device is off.  For example, if you turn off a PC, the monitor and printer might be shut down.  There are a number from major vendors [This](http://www.smarthomeusa.com/ShopByManufacturer/Bits-Ltd./Item/LCG5/) is just one example.

The under monitor units are convenient and I also used one for many years.

One caution.  Most Inkjet printers should not be shut down at a surge supressor or power bar.  Always use on device power switch.

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I've had the same unit since the 90s. It was only minutes ago, did the Printer light spark and go out (and of course trip the breaker for the entire room I was in (the UPS unit that was feeding my Power Center just now justified it's purchase)).

My searching showed that the [Tripp Lite TMC-6 6-Outlet Under Monitor Surge Protector](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AKA90) looks like a great replacement ($30 at the time of this writing) and there's also it's big brother ([MT-6PLUS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000512E1)) with some other features for a little over twice the price.

The sparks I mentioned earlier happened minutes ago...and shortly thereafter, so did my purchase of the $30 unit.